# How to re-arrange text string?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have the following list of text.
Employee - 1 
Customer - 37 
Manager - 874

What String functions would be helpful to re-arrange them as follows ?
1 - Employee 
37 - Customer 
874 - Manager

Thanks!

Comment: [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this sample text:

```
Dim text As String = "" & vbCrLf & _
            "Employee - 1" & vbCrLf & _
            "Customer - 37" & vbCrLf & _
            "Manager - 874"
```

You can use `String.Split` and `String.Join` and some LINQ "magic" like `Reverse`:

```
Dim swappedLines As IEnumerable(Of String) =
    From line In text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
    Select String.Join(" - ", line.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.None).Reverse())
text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, swappedLines)
```

Comment: Fantastic, Fabuloso, Fantastique...

Thanks!